# Merge CSV columns with irregular timestamps and different header names per file

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I have long CSV files with different headers in every file.
The first column is always a timestamp which is irregular with its timings, so it rarely matches.

file1.csv

```
time,L_pitch,L_roll,L_yaw
2020-08-21T09:58:07.570,-0.0,-6.1,0.0
2020-08-21T09:58:07.581,-0.0,-6.1,0.0
2020-08-21T09:58:07.591,-0.0,-6.1,0.0
....
```

file2.csv

```
time,R_pitch,R_roll,R_yaw
2020-08-21T09:58:07.591,1.3,-5.7,360.0
2020-08-21T09:58:07.607,1.3,-5.7,360.0
2020-08-21T09:58:07.617,1.3,-5.7,360.0
....
```

file3.csv

```
time,L_accel_lat,L_accel_long,L_accel_vert
2020-08-21T09:58:07.420,-0.00,-0.00,0.03
2020-08-21T09:58:07.430,-0.00,0.00,0.03
2020-08-21T09:58:07.440,-0.00,0.00,0.03
....
```

At the moment there can be up to 6 CSV files in that format in a folder.

I would like to merge these CSV into one file where all columns are recognized and sorted according to the timestamps. When timestamps are matching, data gets merged into its corresponding line. If time is not matched, it gets a separate line with empty fields.

The result should look like this.

```
time,L_pitch,L_roll,L_yaw,R_pitch,R_roll,R_yaw,L_accel_lat,L_accel_long,L_accel_vert
2020-08-21T09:58:07.420,,,,,,,-0.00,-0.00,0.03
2020-08-21T09:58:07.430,,,,,,,-0.00,0.00,0.03
2020-08-21T09:58:07.440,,,,,,,-0.00,0.00,0.03
....
2020-08-21T09:58:07.581,-0.0,-6.1,0.0,,,,,,
2020-08-21T09:58:07.591,-0.0,-6.1,0.0,1.3,-5.7,360.0,,,
```

Last line would be an example of a matching timecode and with this also datamerging into one line

So far I tried this [Github Link](https://github.com/jagilber/powershellScripts/blob/master/log-merge.ps1), but this merges with filenames into the CSV and no sorting.
[Panda in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717819/merge-csv-files-with-timestamps) seems to be up to the task, but my skills are not. I also tried some python files from GitHub...

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019303/how-to-merge-all-contents-in-two-csv-files-where-records-match-off-1-column) one seemed the most promising with changing the user, but it runs with no end (files to big?).

Is this possible to do this in a PowerShell ps1 or a somewhat (for me) "easy" python script?
I would build this into a batch file to work in several folders.

Thanks in advance

goam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can solve your problems rather conveniently using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

tmp=[]
for f in glob.glob("file*"):
    print(f)
    tmp.append(pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0, parse_dates=True))

pd.concat(tmp,axis=1,sort=True).to_csv('merged')
```

Some explanation:

Here, we use `glob` to get the list of files using the wildcard pattern `file*`. We loop over this list and read each file using pandas `read_csv`. Note, we parse the dates of the file (converts to dtype `datetime64[ns]`) and use the date column as an index of the dataframe. We store the dataframes in a list called `tmp`. Finally we concatinate the individual dataframes (of the individual files) in tmp using `concat` and immediately write it to a file called `merged.csv` using pandas `to_csv`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is basically it.
Small additional question. Is it somehow possible to maintain the timeformat?
It removes the "T" between date and time and my software has problems reading it like  that. I can always make a small script to replace this after the fact so no big problem. But maybe it is possible in one round?

Comment: @goamberg, You can check [the docs of `to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and find that it accepts a paramter called `date_format`. If you specify `date_format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s.%f'` you convert to the desired date format when writing to the file.